# How can i visibility to true in android studio?

Tags: android

I have a problem,i write this in my activity xml file:

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:visibility="invisible"  />
```

i want when i click in button my fragment visibile to true.How can i do this?
i want set visible in java class code,into button click event.

Comment: why in `Android Studio` ?

Comment: Bad question. How do you initialize fragment? Did you attach it? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can initialize fragment by....

```
MapFragment fragment=(YourFragment ) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

then getView() and set visibility....

```
fragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: are the fragment detect into java class file?into button click event?

Comment: first you have to initialize that fragment by getFragmentManager().findViewById();   
then getView() and set the Visibility...

Comment: what is Yourfragment?my xml file this:<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:visibility="invisible"  />